# Is there a smart way to check if for each key in a hash table, they all have the same value?

Tags: java, hashtable

Is there a smart way to check if all keys map to the same value? So the hash table will be as below:

```
a=>2;
b=>2;
c=>2;
d=>2;
```

So a,b,d,c and d all map to the same val. I am asking because I have to find the maximum occurrence of a number in a list but it no number is the clear max, I should just print "None". So if 2 number have the max, it means no number is the clear max in terms of occurrence. Also, how do I check if there's no clear max in the values.

Below is what I have so far but it always returns "None":

```
 private static void getMaxOccrrance(String a) {
    String[] sNew = a.split(",");

    Hashtable<Integer,Integer> nums = new Hashtable<>();

    for(String x : sNew) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(x);
        if (!nums.containsKey(num)) {
            nums.put(num, 1);
        } else {
            nums.put(num, nums.get(num) + 1);
        }
    }

    int  val = 0, max = 1;
    for(int keys : nums.keySet()){
        if(nums.get(keys) > max){
            val = keys;
            max = nums.get(keys);
        }
    }

    boolean uniqueMax = true;
    int count = 0;

      for(int values : nums.values()){
        if(val == values) {
            count++;
            if(count >= 2){
                uniqueMax = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(uniqueMax){
        System.out.println(val);
    }else {
        System.out.println("None");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an XY problem. In case where a, b and c have value 2 and d has value 1, you still have no clear maximum, but not all keys map to the same value.

Comment: the number 2 occurs 4 times. 2 is clearly the maximally occurring number.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. But I want a smart way to determine if there's no clear max

Comment: @KwekuBlue well, assuming there is a clear max, how would you determine it?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?  What would be a “not so smart but practically working” solution?

Comment: Well, to see if all the keys map to the same value, you could make a `Set` of some type, passing the map's `values` collection to its constructor, then check whether its size is 1.  But that won't help you much with the broader problem.

Comment: @5gon12eder I did try something. I pasted the code

Comment: The problem is in your last loop.  You are unconditionally overwriting `val` and incrementing `count`.  You should only do that if `values == val`.  You could improve your code a lot by using less confusing variable names (plural vs singular among others).  Finally, you could combine it all into a single loop which would be more elegant and probably also faster.

Comment: I made that change already before your comment. But thanks though. Unfortunately, it still does not work. Check the update

Comment: You also should initialize `max` with 0, not 1.  If I fix that, the code seems to work.  I say “seems” because you have provided an incomplete example and I have to make several assumptions such as that `Hashtable` actually means `java.util.HashMap`.

Comment: Using java.util.Hashtable and no it does not work. But thanks though. I'll work through it later on

Comment: If this `new HashSet<>(table.values()).size()` returns `1`, then each key has the same value.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with Map in a single thread, much more efficient to keep&update this information directly on Map operations, if they are always non-decreasing by value `put()`s. E. g.

```
class MyMap<K> {
    Map<K, Integer> impl;
    K singleMaxKey;
    int maxValue;

   public void put(K key, int value) {
        if (value > maxValue) {
            maxValue = value; 
            singleMaxKey = key;
        } else if (value == maxValue && !key.equals(singleMaxKey)) {
            sibgleMaxKey = null;
        }
        impl.put(key, value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Java 8 you can do this fairly easily using streams. The following will return a map from each distinct value in a list to its frequency:

```
Map<Value, Integer> getFrequencyMap(Collection<Value> list) {
    return list.stream().distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(value -> value, value -> Collections.frequency(list, value));
}
```

You can call this with `map.values()` to get the frequency of all values in the your map.

If you wish to determine if there is more than one value that occurs the same, maximum number of times, you can check the new frequency map to see if the value occurs more than once:

```
Map<Key, Value> map;
Map<Value, Integer> valueFrequencies = getFrequencyMap(map.values());
int maxFrequency = valueFrequencies.values().stream().max().orElse(0);
if (Collections.frequency(valueFrequencies.values(), maxFrequency) > 1) {
    // no clear max frequency
}
```